# Two argument date function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have two dates: `'24 October 2017'` and `'4/7/2018'`.

If the two dates are the same return `True`.

If the two dates are different return `False`.

This is the function I currently have but I am unable to figure out how to get the month names associated with their respective number.

```
def date_func(a,b):
    y = a.split(" ")
    z = b.split("/")
    if y[1] + y[0] + y[2] == z[0] + z[1] + z[2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried creating a dictionary but am unsure on how to use it.

```
month_dict = {'Month' : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], 'Number' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) module

```
from datetime import date

date_1 = datetime.strptime("4/7/2018", "%d/%m/%Y")

date_2 = datetime.strptime("24 October 2017", "%d %B %Y")

date_1 == date_2 # False
```

Have a look at [strptime/strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use a list then `list.index` to get the position. But since lists are 0-indexed, we need to add one to get the result.

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

print(months.index('October')+1)  # -> 10
```

Note that `list.index` returns an int, so to compare it to the other month value, you'll need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

While the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) module provides a nice interface to dates and similar concepts, I expect that you are more interested to do this for the sake of the exercise itself.

The structure of your dictionary `month_dict` is a bit weird. Currently it maps one big list of months to another big list of integers. What you want is a mapping between each month and its corresponding number. Check it out:

```
def date_func(a,b):
    y = a.split(" ")
    z = b.split("/")
    if month_dict[y[1]] + y[0] + y[2] == z[0] + z[1] + z[2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
month_dict = {
    'January'  : '1',
    'February' : '2',
    'March'    : '3',
    'April'    : '4',
    'May'      : '5',
    'June'     : '6',
    'July'     : '7',
    'August'   : '8',
    'September': '9',
    'October'  : '10',
    'November' : '11',
    'December' : '12',
}


# Test
print(date_func('24 October 2017', '4/7/2018'))    # False
print(date_func('24 October 2017', '10/24/2017'))  # True
```

Note also that the "integers" in the dictionary is quoted, i.e. they are `str`'s and not `int`'s, as to allow the to be added together with the other `str`'s.

### Note on bug

While I believe the above does what you intended, let me point out a bug:
Your strategy of string concatenation is not perfect, as demonstrated by both of these calls returning `True`:

```
date_func('1 November 2017' , '11/1/2017')
date_func('11 January 2017' , '11/1/2017')
```

(in both cases, `month_dict[y[1]] + y[0] == '111'`). The solution is to compare each of the three integers separately, which is most nicely done by first putting them into a container. Below I chose a `list`, as I can then compare directly with `z`:

```
def date_func(a,b):
    y = a.split(" ")
    z = b.split("/")
    if [month_dict[y[1]], y[0], y[2]] == z:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```